# Which language gives more efficiency for string pattern matching?

Tags: string, performance, pattern-matching, string-matching

I want to implement a searching algorithm for sequence of words. For that i need good efficiency for handling string operations.

Comment: What type of string operations you are trying to do?

Comment: The quality of your algorithms is going to be way more important than your choice of language.

Comment: I recommend [SNOBOL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SNOBOL).

Comment: If it has to be fast, use a tool like flex to generate highly optimized code for your particular patterns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It completely depends on the *kind* of string pattern-matching you're expecting to perform. For example, Perl has an excellent and very efficient regular expression matcher.

Answer (score 1):

If you're after regex, [this](http://swtch.com/~rsc/regexp/regexp1.html) is really cool. I'm not sure if anyone has taken this and implemented it in a way that is useful. But practically, grep and perl are the tools I use most often and prove to be 'fast enough' in most cases. They handle the hard parts. "Matching a sequence of words" isn't hard.